# tslint import is declared but its value is never read false positive

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, tslint

In my ionic project ts code I use Refresher from ionic-angular

```
import { NavController, Refresher } from 'ionic-angular';
...
export class myClass {
  refresh: BehaviorSubject<{ searchTerm: string; refresher: Refresher }>;
...
```

However I get the error `'Refresher' is declared but its value is never read.`
If I delete the import the code obviously doesn't compile.

What is the underlying cause here ? I know how to ignore the error and I don't want to do that, I want to actually understand and fix it.